# SSH.NET Public Key Authentication

Tags: c#, ssh, ssh.net

I know that [private key authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41535271/3103633) works, however I'm looking for public key authentication.

I'm trying to establish a connection using SSH.NET and a public key.

In the Git Bash terminal I can connect and run commands fine using my public key, but when I try connecting to the same host using SSH.NET I get an exception.

Here is my how I'm trying to connect:

```
using (var client = new SshClient("host.name.com", port, "username"))
{
    client.Connect(); // exception thrown here
}
```

I've also tried this route:

```
var authMethod = new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod("username");
var info = new ConnectionInfo("host.name.com", port, "username", authMethod);
using (var client = new SshClient(info))
```

Both give the same exception: `Permission denied (publickey).`

It seems as though I need to specify where my public key is, or I need to put my public key in a certain spot, but I can't find any documentation telling me where to put it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no *"private key authentication"*. It's actually called *"public key authentication"*.

Though you need **both private and public key** to authenticate using *"public key authentication"*. It's called *"public key authentication"*, because a client (SSH.NET in this case) sends only the *public* key to the server – So the server authenticates you using the *public key* only. The *private key* is used locally only.

Though file formats that are commonly referred to as a *private key* (like PEM or .ppk) – as opposite to *public key* (.pub) formats – actually contain whole key pair (*both public and private key*).

So the question that you link to – [SSH.NET Authenticate via private key only (public key authentication)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30667142/850848) – actually does what you want. It shows how to authenticate using *"public key authentication"* – using *private key* file format (*both public and private key* really). I've edited the title of that question to make this more clear.

---

And to correct you, it's not true that *"In the Git Bash terminal I can connect and run commands fine using my public key"* – That's not possible. You must have a private key too.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I was under the assumption that the two were different because the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40974288/3103633 suggests that.